Custom colors in a legacy VTK file
I am creating a visualization of 3D data within a library. To avoid an additional dependency, I am manually writing a VTK file. In the following file, I have defined 16 custom colors. It should display a white triangle and three green edges. However, Paraview shows the elements in purple. Is the file incorrect, or does Paraview need different settings to use the custom lookup table? (I'm new to Vtk and Paraview)
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
[tri.vtk]
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 3 double
57.5705 20.2168 -5.50896
58.3134 19.2945 -5.50003
58.8049 20.5207 -5.26131
LINES 3 9
2 0 1
2 1 2
2 2 0
POLYGONS 1 4
3 0 1 2
CELL_DATA 4
SCALARS scalars float 1
LOOKUP_TABLE CellColors
1 1 1 7
LOOKUP_TABLE CellColors 16
1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
0.5 0.5 0.5 1
1 0.65 0 1
1 0.75 0.800001 1
0.680001 0.850001 0.9 1
0 0.100001 0.803 1
0.560001 0.930001 0.560001 1
0.647001 0.165001 0.165001 1
0.627 0.125 0.941 1



LINES seems correct, I have 3 lines and 9 numbers follow, right? In my opinion the line 1 1 1 7 specifies the color "0 1 0 1" for the first three cells which are the lines, while the polygon gets color 7, "1 1 1 1". It may be wrong, the documentation is somewhat unclear.

I think you've got two different types of cells in there, lines and polygons.  You CELL_DATA field can't be applied to both of them.  I think you need a separate ones for the lines and the polygons.

Thanks, but it works that way. The indices were wrong. I have answered my own question below.

I'm answering my own question here to save others time in the future:
I expected the 16 colors in the custom lookup table to be indexed with integers from 0 to 15. However, the indices are in fact floats in the range 0 to 1.0, i.e., the index for color i is computed i/(NUMCOLORS-1). This was counter-intuitive to me. Here is a complete example with colored triangles, edges and vertices:
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Geom Fade 2.5D [tri.vtk]
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 4 double
18.8733 100 10
22.6792 0 -10
89.0149 100 0.390667
100 0 5.03986
VERTICES 4 8
1 1
1 0
1 2
1 3
LINES 6 18
2 1 2
2 2 0
2 0 1
2 3 2
2 2 1
2 1 3
POLYGONS 2 8
3 1 2 0
3 3 2 1
CELL_DATA 12
SCALARS scalars float 1
LOOKUP_TABLE cell_colors
1 1 1 1 0.466667 0.466667 0.466667 0.466667 0.466667 0.466667 0 0.0666667 
LOOKUP_TABLE cell_colors 16
1 0 0 1
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 1
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1
0.5 0.5 0.5 1
1 0.65 0 1
1 0.75 0.800001 1
0.680001 0.850001 0.9 1
0 0.100001 0.803 1
0.560001 0.930001 0.560001 1
0.647001 0.165001 0.165001 1
0.627 0.125 0.941 1


